# Is this probability statement true?

Tags: probability

$X,Y,Z$ are random variables. If $\mathbb{E}Y \geq \mathbb{E}Z$, can we claim $P(X>Y) \leq P(X>Z)$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $Y$ be a pmf with weight $1/2$ at each of $0$ and $1$.  $\mathbb{E}Y = 1/2$.  Let $Z$ be a pmf with weight $1/2$ at each of $-3$ and $3$.  $\mathbb{E}Z = 0 \leq \mathbb{E}Y$.

Let $X$ be a pmf with weight $1$ at $2$.  $P(X>Y) = 1 \not \leq 1/2 = P(X>Z)$.

Exactly the same "trick" can be accomplished with continuous distributions, but this discrete distribution example is very clear about what the cause is -- expectation values tell you nothing about how wide a distribution is.

Comment: Also note that this example can be modified to make $P(X>Z)$ arbitrarily close to $0$.  Make $Z$ have a tiny weight at a really huge negative number and all the rest at $3$.

Answer (score 2):

The result does not hold. You can undoubtedly find a simple discrete example, but here is a continuous one.

Let $Y$ have uniform distribution on $[0,1]$, and let $Z$ have exponential distribution with density function $2e^{-2z}$ for $z\gt 0$. Then $E(Y)=E(Z)$.

Let $X$ have very simple distribution, $X=1$ with probability $1$. Then $\Pr(X\gt Y)=1$ while $\Pr(X\gt Z)=1-e^{-2}$.